# PHP - File upload affected by filename length

Tags: php, pdf

I seem to be having an issue regarding uploading PDF's and from my testing it seems to be a filename length issue?

An example PDF file is 24KB in size.

If I try to upload the PDF with a filename like this - A SHAK Price List Jack's Paint01042014.pdf - I get a 500 Internal Server Error with nothing in the server error log.

if I upload the same PDF with a filename of - A SHAK Pricelist.pdf - it uploads fine without a problem.

The filename is changed to a unique 10 digit code when upload is successful.

I am doubtful that the original PDF filename length is really the cause but could it be? Thanks

**My PHP Configuration**

```
file_uploads - On
max_execution_time - 600
max_input_time - 60
memory_limit - 256M
register_globals - Off
upload_max_filesize - 32M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually testing, I suspect the apostrophe could be causing a problem. Try the whole length of the file name again, but without the apostrophe. If this is the case, you might want to encode the file name. `A SHAK Price List Jacks Paint01042014.pdf`

Answer (score 1):

add `addslashes(your_filename)` before uploading it to server, it will automatically add \ before special character that can cause string break. 
Hope this help :)